# Split string by character and separate it with comma in C#

Tags: c#, string

How can I separate string by character and separate each of them by comma?

I have for example `value = '1234';` and I want to transform it to: `value = '1,2,3,4'`. So it should still be string (not an array of numbers).

I've tried this out:

```
var result = "1234";
var fResult = string.Join(",", result.Split());
```

But I did not have any success. I've got again `result = "1234";`
Where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Split is used to break a delimited string into substrings. Your string isn't delimited. What is your criteria for splitting your string? Is it every character?

Comment: With '1234' you need some form of delimiter, which you obviously don't have.
Split returns an array.
If you know that each character will only be one character in length, the you could loop thru the result string and take one character at a time and build a new string = 1,2,3,4 etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take string as char array then Join again with comma

```
var result = "1234";
var fResult = string.Join(",", result.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

`Join` your `string` as `IEnumerable<char>`

```
string input = "1234";  
string result = string.Join(",",input.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it doesn't make an additional copy of the chars in the string.

Comment: I cant get this one to work. Is there something missing?
'string' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

this demo for you:

```
var result = "1234";
var data = result.ToCharArray();
var fResult = string.Join(",", data);
```